# Laravel ajax post calls fails

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I found several solutions to this one, tried them all (csrf tokens, urls..) but none of them seems to work.

This is my setup:

html file:

```
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

...

    <button id="button" class="btn btn-success">Assign Selected</button>

...
```

My js file:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

 $('#button').click(function (e) {


        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });

        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'json',
                url: '/wptest',
                data: { data: 'ahoj' }
            }).done(function (data) {
                console.log('Ajax was Successful!')
                console.log(data)
            }).fail(function () {
                console.log('Ajax Failed')
            });
    });

}
```

And my web.php file:

```
Route::post('/wptest','UserController@assignToWP');
```

In my controller there is just a simple dd($request);

Edit: network tab shows: 200 OK

Problem: I always get Ajax Failed after button click. What do I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the solution:

The whole problem is, that in order for ajax to be successful, the controller needs to pass and return. `dd` function kills the controller before return and ajax fail therefore.

Make sure controller always gets to its return line.